# Moments and density tails

Tags: probability, density-function, moments

Assume that the first $n$ moments $m_1,\dots\,m_n$ of a random variable $X\in\mathbb{R}$ are known, but not its probability density function $p(x)$.

Does there exist a methodology to characterize the tail behaviour of the p.d.f ?

For example whether $p(x)\sim |x|^{-\theta}$ or  $p(x)\sim e^{-\theta \, |x|^\gamma}$.

Comment: Did you look at truncated moment problems?

Answer (score 8):

If two distributions $X$ and $Y$ have the same moments from 0 up to $n$, then the CDFs of the two functions differ asymptotically by less than $x^{-n}$. See [this page](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/11/16/how-well-do-moments-determine-a-distribution/) for details and references.

Comment: That's interesting and useful, but does it tell us anything at all about the tails of either distribution?